# How to split a Gridview in more webpages in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, html

I want to know how can i use a **GridView** in **ASP.NET** to print out a table from my database, something like :

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM PERSOANE", myConn);
SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sqlDA.Fill(ds, "PERSOANE");

GridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
GridView.DataSource = ds;
GridView.DataBind();
```

but I'd like to **span it across pages** so in case the database contains **1000 entries**, there should be **100 pages** with **10 entries** each page, but I would not like to make the pages manually (or programmatic for that matter) but to send the info needed in the page, something like www.domainname.domain/LoadView.aspx?page=2 , but **i don't know how can i tell the grid view load from the 10th item to the 20th**. So that is my question .

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Custom-Paging-in-ASP.Net-GridView-using-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure.aspx

Comment: Enable paging on your gridview (in your .aspx page gridview declaration), then get the querystring value, then set the current page to grdView.PageIndex = querystringNumber; and you could even disabled your paging controls if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the gridview's
 GridViewSample.PageIndex = 2 ;
or what ever value (page=2), which you are passing through as a QueryString.